# Ninject Custom Inject Attribute

Tags: attributes, ninject, inject

Could someone point me in the direction of how to create a custom "Inject" attribute with Ninject?

I would like to do the following:

- InjectView - custom "inject" attribute

When a property with this attribute is to be injected, the injected value is to be loaded from a "ViewManager" class.

I found an example with ISelector to decide if the property / filed is to be injected, however I couldn't find out how to add a custom "injection strategy" for this - I would like to delegate the injection of the actual value to my ViewManager.

Answer (score 4):

It's already supported and can be done with a simple configuration of the kernel.

```
new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { InjectAttribute = typeof(MyOwnInjectAttribute) };
```

Comment: The thing is that this just supports changing which attribute is used for the injection. What I would like is that each property with this property will get the value from a "specific provider", and I also need to access the attribute before deciding what value is to be injected. For example:

[InjectViewRegion(Id = Infrastructure.ViewRegions.Login)]
private IViewRegion LoginViewRegion { get; set; }

When injecting the value for this property, I want to access the InjectViewRegion attribute, and the the view region registered for the specified "Id".

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding a custom IInjectionHeuristic which allows injecting by my custom attribute. Then I also added a custom IBindingResolver which adds an additional binding per type that is resolved - this binding has a condition checking for the custom attribute, so that it doesn't break any previous bindings...

Tha bindings created by the custom IBindingResolver sets a local "ProviderCallback", which utilizes the extracted property and passes the request to an internal ViewRegionManager instance.

Hope this helps in case anyone wants to do something similar in the future.